# Login box becomes too wide when screen size is adjusted

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and [a login form snippet](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/login-amp-signup-forms-in-panel) with the idea to have a login screen next to some text.

The HTML and CSS I am using to accomplish this works reasonably well, until the screen size is adjusted. When the screen gets smaller the login box starts to get bigger (specifically, the whole box gets a larger width and the label-heading becomes of bigger height). It becomes so big that the text in the left column just disappears.

I am okay with this resizing (on a device with a smaller screen there is no room for text so then it is better to only have a login box), but I do not want it too become of a bigger height and have it resize in disproportionate ways (e.g., the text of "forgot password" comes on top of the title and the text boxes stay small while the label gets bigger).

Screenshot full-width (reasonably happy with this):

[image: Okay]

Screenshot smaller-width (not happy with this):

[image: Not okay]

HTML: (CSS is bootstrap.css)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 pull-left">
        <div style="padding: 3.5%; padding-top: 30px">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h2>Welkom bij de Zaaikalender.</h2>
                <p>Blablabla...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Login box inspired by http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/login-amp-signup-forms-in-panel -->
    <div id="loginbox" style="padding: 3.5%; font-size: 10px;" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">                    

        <div class="panel panel-info" >

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">Inloggen</div>
                <div style="float: right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Wachtwoord vergeten?</a></div>
            </div>     

            <div style="padding-top: 30px" class="panel-body" >

                <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

                <form action="/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="BrShx6jCTpSqw1mUw0DrxKrB8vrIRW1he1T-FycNwwMLNtwvtJwvhshhomZF5zStLJ43lP9PbuxmB4TIO8Qmcwatd7P6AavYQOW4nfCWZn41" />                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>                                   
                        <span>
                            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="*" id="UserName" name="UserName" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam of e-mailadres" type="text" value="" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="*" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Wachtwoord" type="password" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label style="color: black;">
                                <input class="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The field Onthoud mij? is invalid." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="1" /><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" />
                                Onthoud mij.
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="form-group">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login  </button>
                            <a id="btn-fblogin" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Login met Facebook</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12 control">
                            <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top: 15px; font-size: 85%; color: black;" >
                                Ik heb nog geen account! 
                                <a href="Register" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').show()">
                                    Registreren.
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </form>
            </div><!-- End panel body -->
        </div><!-- End panel -->
    </div><!-- End login box column-->
</div><!-- End row -->
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2977/

Does anyone see why it resizes in such an ugly way while increasing the screen width? And if so, how can it be made to resize in a way so everything stays in the proportions they are in while bigger?

Thanks.

Comment: after a quick look i found out you use percentages for some widths, the problem might be there.. 'sorry, out of time to read it all'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be fixed by adding the class `col-xs-6` to both divs, just adjusted this in your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gxge043/). This fixes it because then the width will be 50% for smaller viewpoints.

For more detailed information about using the bootstrap grid you could check e.g. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 2):

I'd try applying the padding you have inline on the right column to the panel-info child div as margin instead.  It is probably messing up the bootstrap column widths. Also, why are you using a jumbotron class for the left div?

Comment: Jumbotron is used to make it look more pretty. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Putting it to the panel-info makes the panel info take up all the room it got plus more. Does not look good.